# How to IF EXISTS ELSE with Mysql?

Tags: mysql

sorry in advance if I make mistakes, I don't speak English.

I want something similar to :

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE condition1 AND condition2) 
   THEN
       UPDATE table SET exemple WHERE condition1
   ELSE 
       SELECT 1 FROM articles WHERE condition1
END IF;
```

But i've tried many things and not worked

Fore resume :
I want to recover the select if the update could not be done.
(I specify that it is of the MySQL language)

Anyone one for help me ? thanks!

Comment: This could be done in a stored procedure.

Comment: I didn't know about this feature, now I have achieved what I wanted to do. Thanks a lot !